# How to Attach Entity in Entity Freamework Core 2.0 Preview?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create a one method using which i can Add/Update entity using Entity Framework 2.0-Preview.
I am using Insert Update Pattern.
For more Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx (Last example)

Below is a method code:

```
    public string AttachEntity(Book book)
    {
        _context.Entry(book).State = (book.Id == 0)
            ? Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added
            : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
        string msg = $"Book details {_context.Entry(book).State} Successfully";

        _context.Book.Attach(book);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return msg;
    }
```

and got below error:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' on entity type 'Book' has
>   a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to
>   'Unchanged'. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that
>   the database is configured to generate values for this property.

However Id is auto generated for book table. 
 
and below urls for that action:
[For add] Home/AttachEntity?Id=1&Title=4th book&Description=New book added by attach method&Price=120&AuthorId=2
[For update] Home/AttachEntity?Title=4th book&Description=New book added by attach method&Price=120&AuthorId=2